# Update query to replace 003 to 030 in a 9 digit values of a field in table in access

Tags: ms-access

I have an access table with a numeric field. It was 9 digit field and all values start with 003, But I want it to start with 030. Please help me to make an update query to solve this problem.

Comment: If it's a field whose values all start with `003` then it is not a numeric field, it's a Text field.

Answer (score 1):

assuming you have string column  of 9 char length you could repalce  the leftmost 3 char using

```
    update my_table  
    set my_column = '030' & right(my_column, 6)
    where left(my_column,3) = '003'
```

Comment: Thank you sir, but the colum starts with other than 003 not to be changed, is it possible

Comment: based  on my query all the rows should be updated .. (there is not a where clause so all the rows  are involved)

Comment: Thanks,this query works well, But I have some more different situation, the first three digits may have other patterns than 003, I want to change only this pattern 003, others will remain as it is. Can you please help me?

Comment: @JayakumarParameswaranPillai  answer  updated for 003 starting rows